# Highstock flag position not correct for yAxis with top set

Tags: highcharts

Here seems highstock is not working as expected

http://jsfiddle.net/gCuLJ/1/

I simply created a highstock chart with yaxis with fixed top and height.

Then i added a new y-axis with top and height set as to stack the chart below the first one.

Now i set some flags on the second y-Axis series.

Flags are showing somewhere on first y-Axis series.

add button handler code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.addAxis({
        id:'secondY',            
        top:300,// making this 140 positions flags correctly
        height:150
    });

    chart.addSeries({
        id:'adbe',
        yAxis:'secondY',
        name: 'ADBE', 
        data: ADBE
    });
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    chart.addSeries(
    // the event marker flags
        {
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'G',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bulls Clear Path to 1.50 Figure'
            }],
            onSeries : 'adbe',
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        });


});
```

Comment: Reported by author at [github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2425).

Comment: when adding the new series use yAxis:'secondY'

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nmccready/wXZ4H/1/ and https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2425 .

You need to assign an id to whatever yAxis you need.

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            marginTop: 100, //avoid overlapping with navigator
            spacingLeft: 0
        },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        top: 40
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    yAxis:[{
        id: 'firstY',
        top:140,
        height:150
    }],
    series: [{
        id:'msft',
        name: 'MSFT',            
        data: MSFT,
        yAxis: 'firstY'
    }]
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.addAxis({
        title:'duh',
        id:'secondY',            
        top:300,
        height:150
    });

    chart.addSeries({
        id:'adbe',
        yAxis:'secondY',
        name: 'ADBE', 
        data: ADBE
    });
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    chart.addSeries(
    // the event marker flags
        {
        yAxis:'firstY',
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'G',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bulls Clear Path to 1.50 Figure'
            }],
            onSeries : 'msft',
            shape : 'circlepin',
            width : 16
        });



});
```

});